# Cloud Foundry v2 on Openstack

Tags: cloud-foundry, openstack

I would like to know how are the steps to run cloud foundry on openstack? Is there any tutorial or steps for the new version of Cloud Foundry. I have tried the method which was posted in here https://gist.github.com/yudai/5832367. But i have the following errors.

```
syck has been removed, psych is used instead
/home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/yaml_helper.rb:48:in check_duplicate_keys': Cannot find Syck parser for YAML, please check your Ruby installation (RuntimeError)
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/core_ext.rb:76:in load_yaml_file'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/config.rb:49:in initialize'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/base_command.rb:38:in new'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/base_command.rb:38:in config'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/base_command.rb:96:in target'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/base_command.rb:168:in target_required'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/base_command.rb:163:in auth_required'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/commands/release.rb:87:in upload'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/command_handler.rb:57:in run'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/runner.rb:61:in run'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/runner.rb:18:in run'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/bin/bosh:16:in <top (required)>'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/bosh:23:in load'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/bosh:23:in <main>'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in <main>'
thunder@ubuntu:~/stemcells$ bosh deploy
syck has been removed, psych is used instead
/home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/yaml_helper.rb:48:in check_duplicate_keys': Cannot find Syck parser for YAML, please check your Ruby installation (RuntimeError)
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/core_ext.rb:76:in load_yaml_file'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/config.rb:49:in initialize'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/base_command.rb:38:in new'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/base_command.rb:38:in config'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/base_command.rb:96:in target'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/base_command.rb:168:in target_required'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/base_command.rb:163:in auth_required'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/commands/deployment.rb:87:in perform'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/command_handler.rb:57:in run'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/runner.rb:61:in run'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/lib/cli/runner.rb:18:in run'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bosh_cli-1.0.3/bin/bosh:16:in <top (required)>'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/bosh:23:in load'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/bosh:23:in <main>'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval'
    from /home/thunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in <main>'
```

I'm very new to this fundamental of cloud foundry and openstack. If there is anyone who could me through will be much helpful. As this is my Final year project. Thank you in advanced. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully followed these instructions -http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/openstack/

Answer (score 0):

Deploy Cloud Foundry with [cf-deployment](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/cf-deployment/):

1. Prepare Your Environment OpenStack/BOSH:

   - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/blob/master/iaas-support/openstack/README.md
2. Deploy Cloud Foundry:

   - https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/cf-deployment/deploy-cf.html
   - [Deploying CF Guide](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/blob/master/deployment-guide.md)